# How to set up Netbeans 12 with CCLS for C/C++ programming on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

How do I set up Netbeans 12.3 on Ubuntu 21.04 for C/C++ programming?
In Netbeans the plugin is marked as Temporary, and says it uses CCLS (CC Language Server).
I can install that native with "apt install ccls"
In Netbeans under Tools/Options/C/C++ the path /usr/bin/ccls is set.
In Project Properties there are two options, Editor and Build
For Editor I can guess I write, "gcc hello.c -o hello.out"
For Build, there are Build, Clean and Run data entry textboxes, which I can write:-
Build: "gcc hello.c -o hello.out"
Run: "hello.out"

But nothing works properly.
CCLS search gets me to "https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls", but there is nothing in the Editor Configuration for Netbeans.

Anyone?

Answer (score 4):

Which plugin do you use? `CPPLite Kit` or `C/C++` from NetBeans 8.2 Plugin Portal.
You can try `C/C++`: Open **Plugins** (Tools >> Plugins) window and switch to tab **Settings** and select **NetBeans 8.2 Plugin Portal**. Then go to tab **Available Plugins** and click **Check for Newest** and search for `C/C++`.

If you want to use `CPPLite Kit` you must have `.ccls` file in your project directory. Right click on your project select **Properities** and in the
**Editor** section set path of **Compile Commands** to `.ccls` file in your project folder.

`.ccls` file can contain this:

```
g++
-xc++
-Iinclude
-std=c++17
```

`.ccls` is whole name of the file, not like `something.ccls`.