# Cannot get C++ plugin working in Netbeans 19 on Windows 10 - need unpack200

Tags: c++, netbeans

I have installed Apache Netbeans 19 on my Windows 10 Enterprise laptop. I have also installed JDK 11 on the laptop.

When I go to Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins -> C++, I can open a Wizard to install the plugin. However it always fails at the final stage of installation, with an error 'Cannot complete the validation of downloaded plugins' along with the following error:

```
The validation of downloaded plugins cannot be completed, cause: NBM C:\Users\tlc\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\19\update\download\org-netbeans-modules-cnd-kit.nbm needs unpack200 to process following entries: 
netbeans/modules/locale/org-netbeans-modules-cnd-kit_ja.jar.pack.gz
netbeans/modules/locale/org-netbeans-modules-cnd-kit_pt_BR.jar.pack.gz
netbeans/modules/locale/org-netbeans-modules-cnd-kit_ru.jar.pack.gz
netbeans/modules/locale/org-netbeans-modules-cnd-kit_zh_CN.jar.pack.gz
netbeans/modules/org-netbeans-modules-cnd-kit.jar.pack.gz
```

If I then click the button that appears 'Choose Unpack200', I get another popup at the location C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin where I can see that the unpack200.bin executable is.

However if I click 'OK' on the file browser, nothing happens and it's as if Netbeans can't use unpack200 to proceed.

Can anyone help? I found this post but it is quite outdated and I cannot find the netbeans.conf file that is mentioned.

[How can I set the JDK NetBeans runs on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950960/how-can-i-set-the-jdk-netbeans-runs-on)

Comment: Removed the Java tag because ith isn't a Java programming question. Not a C++ programming question either, but the C++ tag will make it more visible to future C++ programmers also fighting with netbeans.

Comment: [1] File **netbeans.conf** resides in the **etc** directory directly under the NetBeans installation directory. I don't think NetBeans will run without that file, so I'm pretty sure that you must have it. [2] I'm not sure why you are getting a problem when using JDK 11, because **upack200** should be available to you (it was removed in JDK 14), but I hit exactly the same issue as you a couple of years ago. See [this answer and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68043338/2985643) to _Error installing C/C++ plugin in Netbeans 12.4 with JDK 16 in Windows 10_ for more information.

Comment: [3] All that said, I don't think NetBeans currently fully supports C++ in the same way it did in the past. See the question [NetBeans 15 - C++ development (CCLS, GCC)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73673229/2985643), and the comments beneath it.

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact same issue, the only solution I found was downloading unpack200.exe and paste it on C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin. After that, I downloaded C/C++ without issues. I've uploaded the program in Media Fire if you still need it :)
https://www.mediafire.com/file/entgisjivyqduwb/unpack200.zip/file

Comment: Well, downloading an exe from the internet seems harmful for me. Could you share where did you find this binary in the first place to make sure it is a trusted and virus free version?